# If else creates new variable/column but it doesn't appear in R dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I am using an if else statement to convert the values in column X into bins in a new column Y. Code:

```
dat$Y <- mutate(dat, Y = case_when(X <=5 ~ "<5",
                              X <= 10 & X >= 5 ~ "5-10",
                              X <= 15 & X >= 10 ~ "10-15",
                              X <= 20 & X >=15 ~ "15-20",
                              X <= 25 & X >=20 ~ "20-25", 
                              X >= 25 ~ ">25"))
```

When I run this code it says my dataframe has added a new variable (eg. 20 variables originally to 21 after new column is made), however when I click to open my dataframe, it says there are 41 columns, (20 original and 20 that are labeled the same except start with Y (new column header) - mini example of dataframe below. My code has also not worked and my ifelse statement did not run (new column labeled Y.Y has NAs in every row.

Does anyone know how I fix this problem? Is there a problem with my ifelse statement? I am using RStudio, not sure if that matters/impacts this.

Original dataframe:

```
cn  N  Ex   P.col P.bin      X  
 8  1  a   0 1000            15
10  2  b   1000 1000-2000    29
16  3  a   2050 2000-3000    17
11  4  e   421   <500        8
 9  5  d   4050 >4000        22
15  6  c   4400 >4000        13
 9  7  a   1280  1000-2000   3
13  8  a   1900  1000-2000   12
 8  9  c   4200  >4000       16
15 10  e   3560  3000-4000   21
 # … with 2088 more rows
```

Daframe after applying if else statement:

```
cn  N  Ex   P.col P.bin      X   Y.cn  Y.N   Y.EX  Y.P.col  Y.P.bin   Y.X  Y.Y
 8  1  a   0    1000         15    8    1     a      0     1000        15  NA
10  2  b   1000 1000-2000    29   10    2     b      1000  1000-2000   29  NA
16  3  a   2050 2000-3000    17   16    3     a      2050  2000-3000   17  NA
11  4  e   421    <500       8    11    4     e      421   <500        8   NA
 9  5  d   4050 >4000        22    9    5     d      4050  >4000       22  NA
15  6  c   4400 >4000        13   15    6     c      4400  >4000       13  NA
 9  7  a   1280  1000-2000   3     9    7     a      1280  1000-2000   3   NA
13  8  a   1900  1000-2000   12   13    8     a      1900  1000-2000   12  NA
 8  9  c   4200 >4000        16    8    9     c      4200  >4000       16  NA
15 10  e   3560  3000-4000   21   15   10     e      3560  3000-4000   21  NA
```

Edit: Data

```
structure(list(Temp = c(8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 
8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 
8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 
8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 
8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 
8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 
8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 
8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 
8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 
8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 
8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 
8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 
8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 8.9, 6.3, 6.3, 6.3, 6.3, 6.3, 6.3, 6.3, 6.3, 
6.3, 6.3, 6.3, 6.3, 6.3, 6.3, 6.3, 6.3, 6.3, 6.3, 6.3, 6.3, 6.3, 
6.3, 6.3, 6.3, 13.9, 13.9, 13.9, 13.9, 13.9, 13.9, 13.9, 13.9, 
13.9, 13.9, 13.9, 13.9, 13.9, 13.9, 13.9, 13.9, 13.9, 13.9, 13.9, 
13.9, 13.9, 13.9, 13.9, 13.9, 13.9, 13.9, 13.9, 13.9, 13.9, 13.9, 
13.9, 13.9, 13.9, 13.9, 13.9, 13.9, 13.9, 13.9, 13.9, 13.9, 13.9, 
13.9, 13.9, 13.9, 13.9, 13.9, 13.9, 13.9, 8.7, 8.7, 8.7, 8.7, 
8.7, 8.7, 8.7, 8.7, 8.7, 8.7, 8.7, 8.7, 8.7, 8.7, 8.7, 8.7, 8.7, 
8.7, 8.7, 8.7, 8.7, 8.7, 8.7, 8.7, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 
21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 
21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 21, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 
15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 
15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 
15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 
15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 
15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 
15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 
15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 
15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 
15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 
15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 
15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 15.7, 
5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 
5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 
5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 5.7, 
5.7, 5.7, 5.7, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 
7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 
7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 
7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 
7.2, 7.2, 7.2, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 
8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 
8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, 8.8, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 
9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 
9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 
9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 
9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 
9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 
9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 
9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 
9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 9.3, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 
8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 
8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 
8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 8.5, 
8.5, 8.5, 8.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 
15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 
15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 
15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 
15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 
15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 
15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 
15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 
15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3, 15.3), Precip = c("999", 
"999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", 
"999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", 
"999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", 
"999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", 
"999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", 
"999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", 
"999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", 
"999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", 
"999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", 
"999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", 
"999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", 
"999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", 
"999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", 
"999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", 
"999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", 
"999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "999", "918", 
"918", "918", "918", "918", "918", "918", "918", "918", "918", 
"918", "918", "450", "450", "450", "450", "450", "450", "450", 
"450", "450", "450", "450", "450", "450", "450", "450", "450", 
"450", "450", "450", "450", "450", "450", "450", "450", "615", 
"615", "615", "615", "615", "615", "615", "615", "615", "615", 
"615", "615", "615", "615", "615", "615", "615", "615", "615", 
"615", "615", "615", "615", "615", "615", "615", "615", "615", 
"615", "615", "615", "615", "615", "615", "615", "615", "615", 
"615", "615", "615", "615", "615", "615", "615", "615", "615", 
"615", "615", "680", "680", "680", "680", "680", "680", "680", 
"680", "680", "680", "680", "680", "680", "680", "680", "680", 
"680", "680", "680", "680", "680", "680", "680", "680", "1700", 
"1700", "1700", "1700", "1700", "1700", "1700", "1700", "1700", 
"1700", "1700", "1700", "1700", "1700", "1700", "1700", "1700", 
"1700", "1700", "1700", "1700", "1700", "1700", "1700", "1700", 
"1700", "1700", "1700", "1700", "1700", "1700", "1700", "1700", 
"1700", "1700", "1700", "920", "920", "920", "920", "920", "920", 
"920", "920", "920", "920", "920", "920", "920", "920", "920", 
"920", "920", "920", "920", "920", "920", "920", "920", "920", 
"749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", 
"749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", 
"749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", 
"749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", 
"749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", 
"749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", 
"749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", 
"749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", 
"749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", 
"749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", 
"749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", 
"749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", 
"749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", 
"749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", 
"749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", 
"749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", 
"749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", 
"749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", "749.3", 
"749.3", "749.3", "551", "551", "551", "551", "551", "551", "551", 
"551", "551", "551", "551", "551", "551", "551", "551", "551", 
"551", "551", "551", "551", "551", "551", "551", "551", "551", 
"551", "551", "551", "551", "551", "551", "551", "551", "551", 
"551", "551", "551", "551", "551", "551", "551", "551", "", "", 
"", "", "810", "810", "810", "810", "810", "810", "810", "810", 
"810", "810", "810", "810", "810", "810", "810", "810", "810", 
"810", "810", "810", "810", "810", "810", "810", "810", "810", 
"810", "810", "810", "810", "810", "810", "810", "810", "810", 
"810", "810", "810", "810", "810", "810", "810", "810", "810", 
"810", "810", "810", "810", "479.6", "479.6", "479.6", "479.6", 
"479.6", "479.6", "479.6", "479.6", "479.6", "479.6", "479.6", 
"479.6", "479.6", "479.6", "479.6", "479.6", "479.6", "479.6", 
"479.6", "479.6", "479.6", "479.6", "479.6", "479.6", "479.6", 
"479.6", "479.6", "479.6", "479.6", "479.6", "479.6", "479.6", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "519", "519", 
"519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", 
"519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", 
"519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", 
"519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", 
"519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", 
"519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", 
"519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", 
"519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", 
"519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", 
"519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", 
"519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", "519", 
"519", "519", "519", "652", "652", "652", "652", "652", "652", 
"652", "652", "652", "652", "652", "652", "652", "652", "652", 
"652", "652", "652", "652", "652", "652", "652", "652", "652", 
"652", "652", "652", "652", "652", "652", "652", "652", "652", 
"652", "652", "652", "652", "652", "652", "652", "652", "652", 
"652", "652", "652", "652", "652", "652", "840", "841", "842", 
"843", "844", "845", "846", "847", "848", "849", "850", "851", 
"852", "853", "854", "855", "840", "841", "842", "843", "844", 
"845", "846", "847", "848", "849", "850", "851", "852", "853", 
"854", "855", "840", "841", "842", "843", "844", "845", "846", 
"847", "848", "849", "850", "851", "852", "853", "854", "855", 
"840", "841", "842", "843", "844", "845", "846", "847", "848", 
"849", "850", "851", "852", "853", "854", "855", "840", "841", 
"842", "843", "844", "845", "846", "847", "848", "849", "850", 
"851", "852", "853", "854", "855", "840", "841", "842", "843", 
"844", "845", "846", "847", "848", "849", "850", "851", "852", 
"853", "854", "855", "840", "841", "842", "843", "844", "845", 
"846", "847", "848", "849", "850", "851", "852", "853", "854", 
"855", "840", "841", "842", "843", "844", "845", "846", "847", 
"848", "849", "850", "851", "852", "853", "854", "855", "700", 
"700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", 
"700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", 
"700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", 
"700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", 
"700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", 
"700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", 
"700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", 
"700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", 
"700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", 
"700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", "700", 
"700", "700", "700"), Length = c("L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", 
"I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", 
"I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", 
"I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", 
"I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", 
"I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "I", "I", 
"I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"I", "I", "I", "S", "S", "S", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "I", 
"I", "I", "S", "S", "S", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", "L", 
"L", "L", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "I", "I", "I", "I", 
"I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", 
"I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", 
"I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", 
"I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", 
"I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", 
"I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", 
"I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I", "I"), 
    Range = c("0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", 
    "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", 
    "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", 
    "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", 
    "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", 
    "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", 
    "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", 
    "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", 
    "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", 
    "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", 
    "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", 
    "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", 
    "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", 
    "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", 
    "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", 
    "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", 
    "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", 
    "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", "0-15", 
    "0-15", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
    "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", 
    "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", 
    "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", 
    "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", 
    "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", 
    "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", 
    "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", 
    "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", 
    "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", 
    "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", 
    "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", 
    "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", 
    "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", 
    "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", 
    "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", 
    "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", 
    "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", 
    "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-10", "0-10", "0-10", "0-10", 
    "20-30", "20-30", "20-30", "20-30", "0-10", "0-10", "0-10", 
    "0-10", "20-30", "20-30", "20-30", "20-30", "0-10", "0-10", 
    "0-10", "0-10", "20-30", "20-30", "20-30", "20-30", "0-10", 
    "0-10", "0-10", "0-10", "20-30", "20-30", "20-30", "20-30", 
    "0-10", "0-10", "0-10", "0-10", "20-30", "20-30", "20-30", 
    "20-30", "0-10", "0-10", "0-10", "0-10", "20-30", "20-30", 
    "20-30", "20-30", "0-10", "0-10", "0-10", "0-10", "20-30", 
    "20-30", "20-30", "20-30", "0-10", "0-10", "0-10", "0-10", 
    "20-30", "20-30", "20-30", "20-30", "0-10", "0-10", "0-10", 
    "0-10", "20-30", "20-30", "20-30", "20-30", "0-10", "0-10", 
    "0-10", "0-10", "0-10", "0-10", "0-10", "0-10", "0-10", "0-10", 
    "0-10", "0-10", "0-10", "0-10", "0-10", "0-10", "0-10", "0-10", 
    "0-10", "0-10", "0-10", "0-10", "0-10", "0-10", "0-10", "0-10", 
    "0-10", "0-10", "0-10", "0-10", "0-10", "0-10", "15-May", 
    "15-May", "15-May", "15-May", "15-May", "15-May", "15-May", 
    "15-May", "15-May", "15-May", "15-May", "15-May", "15-May", 
    "15-May", "15-May", "15-May", "15-May", "15-May", "15-May", 
    "15-May", "15-May", "15-May", "15-May", "15-May", "15-May", 
    "15-May", "15-May", "15-May", "15-May", "15-May", "15-May", 
    "15-May", "15-May", "15-May", "15-May", "15-May", "15-May", 
    "15-May", "15-May", "15-May", "15-May", "15-May", "15-May", 
    "15-May", "15-May", "15-May", "15-May", "15-May", "0-25", 
    "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", 
    "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", 
    "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", 
    "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", 
    "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", 
    "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", 
    "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", 
    "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", 
    "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", 
    "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", 
    "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", 
    "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", 
    "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", 
    "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", 
    "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", 
    "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-25", "0-20", 
    "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", 
    "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", 
    "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", 
    "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", 
    "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", 
    "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", 
    "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", 
    "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", 
    "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", 
    "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", 
    "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", 
    "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20", "0-20")), row.names = c(NA, 
1000L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Share a `dput()` of your data so we really know what's inside. Also, you normally don't assign the results of a `mutate()` to a single column. You normally just create a new data.frame with the result.

Comment: `mutate` takes a data frame as the first argument and outputs a data frame. You are creating a whole new dataframe and assigning that to the Y variable of your original data frame. Remove the `$Y` from your first `dat$Y` and you should be fine.

Comment: @MrFlick I just edited my post to add in my data - it is the Temp data that I want to apply the ifelse statement to.

Comment: @Jon Spring I have tried removing the dat$Y but it doesn't run the function then. Is there anther way to run this if else statement?

Comment: When I run `mutate(dat, Y = case_when(Temp <=5 ~ "<5", Temp <= 10 & Temp >= 5 ~ "5-10", Temp <= 15 & Temp >= 10 ~ "10-15", Temp <= 20 & Temp >=15 ~ "15-20", Temp <= 25 & Temp >=20 ~ "20-25",  Temp >= 25 ~ ">25"))` on your test data it seems to work fine. You can just reassign that to your original data.frame `dat <- mutate(...)`

Comment: It should work if you change `dat$Y <- ...` to `dat <- ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please copy and paste this snippet and let us know if it gets the result you want.

```
library(tidyverse)
sample_data <- data.frame(X = c(5,10,15,20,25,30,999))

sample_data <- sample_data %>%
  mutate(
    Y = case_when(
      X <= 5 ~ '<5',
      X > 5 & X <=10 ~ '5-10',
      X > 10 & X <= 15 ~ '10-15',
      X > 15 & X <= 20 ~ '15-20',
      X > 20 & X <= 25 ~ '20-25',
      TRUE ~ '>25'
    )
  )
```